# Redirect from iframe to main window

Tags: google-app-engine, iframe

I have an iframe which when you press a button goes to the main page

```
self.redirect('/')
```

but the problem is that the content of the main page is shown inside the iframe, and I want to show it in the main window (not in the iframe)

How can we get that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question. You like to redirect to your mainpage and remove the iframe.
In your iframe You have to use a button to initiate a redirect and some javascript:

```
<input value="ReDirect" id="button" onclick="parent.parent.location.href ='... url ....';">
```

See also this question : [How to dynamically close an iframe after form submit in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651709/how-to-dynamically-close-an-iframe-after-form-submit-in-javascript)

Comment: yes, you understand well.
The problem with that is that I cant do the redirect onclick because, when you click the button, the app make same validations, and only if pass all of them then do the redirect.

Comment: Maybe you can make a kind of confirmation / continuation page to tell the user the input is correct and they have to press the continue button. I had the same kind of problem, redirecting from a iframe webshop order page to the payment provider.